# How to change input using a value from iterator (JavaScript and Struts2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

we have an bonus exercise in our JavaScript class which I can't solve. I have a problem regarding how to change what is written in the two `<input>` tags depending on which applicant I've chosen. I am retrieving from a database for the `<div>` and `<input>` tags using JavaScript (which is used to connect the front end and back end, I guess) and Struts2.

For example I select "examinee1", the first input should display the name of his/her father while the second input will provide the name of his/her mother. If "examinee2" was chosen, same thing applies.

Here's what I've already started.

```
<div>
    Applicant:
    <select id="examineeList">
       <s:iterator value="examineeList" var="examinee">
            <option value="${examinee.name}" id="${examinee.id}">${examinee.name}</option>
       </s:iterator>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="examineeFather">Father:</label> 
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examineeFather" 
       name="examinee.father" placeholder="-----" maxlength="50" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="examineeMother">Mother:</label> 
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examineeMother" 
       name="examinee.mother" placeholder="-----" maxlength="50" required />
</div>
```

Moreover, if I have not choose any examinee, the input tags should have no value and after selecting the examinee, I can still change the value of 2 input tags whenever I want to (my instructor said that just in case i want to rename my father and mother, lol). Also, If I have selected an examinee, I can save directly with the default value of `father` and `mother` retrieved from the database. After all, saving the entry to the database follows.

Can anybody help me with the JavaScript code? I'm still learning it and only familiar with its basic/usual functions. Any hints and suggestions would be really much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `${examinee.name}` something like that: `${applicant.name}`? Variable is defined here: `<s:iterator value="examineeList" var="applicant">`  And your `option` is empty and should look like this: `<option value="${applicant.name}" id="${applicant.id}">${applicant.name}</option>`

Comment: yes yes you're right, I may have overlooked it. thanks!